# Best way to show and hide table when click a class with same class

Tags: jquery

How can i click any "a" element what has a class that matches a table and show and hide the corresponding table ? I'm capable of doing toggle and specifying each class , but i want something dynamic that will match up any "a" class to any table that has matching class.

Here is sample HTML

```
<a class="franchise_0001">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0004</a>
<a class="franchise_0002">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a>
<a class="franchise_0003">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a>
<a class="franchise_0004">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a>

<table class="franchise_0001" style="display:none">SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0003 is clicked</table>
<table class="franchise_0002" style="display:none">SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0003 is clicked</table>
<table class="franchise_0004" style="display:none">SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0004 is clicked</table>
<table class="franchise_0003" style="display:none">SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0003 is clicked</table>
```

I dont want to declare each one like i have now because the classes can change and i need to have a way to match any up

```
 $("a.franchise_0004").click(function(){
    $("table.franchise_0004").toggle();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the class of any object using `$.attr('class')`.

Get the class and pass it to the table.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("table."+$(this).attr('class')).toggle();
});
```

You can also use a class and toggle this, have a look:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("table."+$(this).attr('class')).toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
}

table.visible {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="franchise_0001">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0004</a><br />
<a class="franchise_0002">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a><br />
<a class="franchise_0003">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a><br />
<a class="franchise_0004">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a><br />
<br />
<table class="franchise_0001">
  <tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0001 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="franchise_0002">
  <tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0002 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="franchise_0003">
  <tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0003 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="franchise_0004">
  <tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0004 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not true about the display toggling between `none` and `block`. From [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/): `The display property is saved and restored as needed.`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thats strange, I was sure it toggled between block and none, even in my test.. but in the documentation its written as restored, have to check this in the dev console right now. thanks for the input

Comment: If you `.hide()` and `.show()`, the previous `display` is not saved... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `same class` on both anchor and table... It would be:

```js
// A click handler that applies on all a having a class starting by "franchise_"
$("a[class^='franchise_']").on("click", function() {

  // Get the full class attribute
  // The split and filter is to allow the table to have additionnal classes...
  // We only need the one starting with "franchise_"
  let myClass = $(this).attr("class").split(" ").filter(c=>c.indexOf("franchise_")>-1)
  
  // Then if we have a class, use it to target the right table
  if(myClass!==""){
    $("table." + myClass).toggle()
  }
})
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
}

table{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="franchise_0001">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0001</a>
<a class="franchise_0002">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0002</a>
<a class="franchise_0003">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a>
<a class="franchise_0004">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0004</a>

<table class="franchise_0001 anotherClass" style="display:none">
<tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0001 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="franchise_0002" style="display:none">
<tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0002 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="franchise_0004" style="display:none">
<tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0003 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="franchise_0003" style="display:none">
<tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0004 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>
```

But the same result can be achieved in a simpler way using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

And I recommand this one over the first because *(in my opinion)* when you have to add numbers to a class to make it "unique"... There always a problem with the logic. A class is intended to regroups "similar" elements.

```js
// A click handler that applies on all a having a class starting by "franchise_"
$("a.franchise").on("click", function() {

  // Get the tableID from the data attribute
  let tableID = $(this).data("table_id")
  
  // Then use it to target the right table
  $("#"+tableID).toggle()
})
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
}

table{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="franchise" data-table_id="F_0001">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0001</a>
<a class="franchise" data-table_id="F_0002">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0002</a>
<a class="franchise" data-table_id="F_0003">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a>
<a class="franchise" data-table_id="F_0004">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0004</a>

<table id="F_0001" style="display:none">
<tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0001 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="F_0002" style="display:none">
<tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0002 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="F_0003" style="display:none">
<tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0003 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="F_0004" style="display:none">
<tr><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0004 is clicked</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```js
$("a").click(function(event){
    var tableClass = $(event.target).attr('class')
    $("table."+tableClass).toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="franchise_0001">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0004</a><br>
<a class="franchise_0002">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a><br>
<a class="franchise_0003">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a><br>
<a class="franchise_0004">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0003</a><br>

<table class="franchise_0001" style="display:none;">
  <tr>
    <td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0001 is clicked</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="franchise_0002" style="display:none;">
  <tr>
    <td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0002 is clicked</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="franchise_0004" style="display:none;">
  <tr>
    <td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0004 is clicked</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="franchise_0003" style="display:none;">
  <tr>
    <td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0003 is clicked</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a bit different as I suggests ways to improve the HTML structure. I would suggest tagging the links with functional tags:

```html
$('.table-toggler').click(function() {
  $($(this).data('opens')).toggle()
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="table-toggler" data-opens=".franchise_0001">CLICK AND SHOW table.franchise_0004</a>

<table class="franchise_0001" style="display:none"><td>SHOW WHEN a.franchise_0003 is clicked</td></table>
```

The reason I chose to add `.table-toggler` to the links is to **indicate their function and eases the query selection process**.

The target is however put into a separate attribute. This is because the link and the table should **not both be called the same class if they are not elements in common**.

I would suggest using id instead of classes if you only want to toggle one table on or off, since classes may refers to some general type of element. If you have many tables called "franchise_0001", then I suggest using other attributes other than class, e.g. data attributes or name.